# UserControl that includes full window overlay

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a sidebar in an application I am writing that displays information about the application's state to the user.  In certain cases, the user can hover over various elements in the sidebar to view more specific details.  These details are shown to the user using a control that mimics the behavior of [Bootstrap's `Popover` control](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers).  I accomplish this using an invisible `Canvas` overlay that spans the entire window, and the "Popover" itself is placed relatively on this `Canvas` using computed `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.

Here's a (very simplified) look at the current XAML of my application:

```
<Window>
  <Grid x:Name="container">

    <.. a lot of various nested elements ..>

      <StackPanel x:Name="sidepanel">
        .. content of the sidepanel control ..
      </StackPanel>

    </.. a lot of various nested elements ..>

  <Canvas x:Name="overlay">
    .. content of the Popover control ..
  </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

This works great, except that I'd like to refactor this functionality into a single control.  However, I'm not sure how to proceed - if the custom `UserControl` includes the `Canvas` overlay in its XAML definition, I'll be unable to position the sidepanel portion of the control in the same way as it currently is positioned within the application.  However, the `Canvas` overlay can't be nested inside of the sidepanel, as it needs to span the entire window in order to operate properly.

Is there a way to define a single `UserControl` that can sit in different parts of the logical tree?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this effect?

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a reason why you cant use the existing [popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control?

Comment: @Benjamin I'm fairly new to WPF, and didn't know about the `Popup` control when I implemented this popover effect a few weeks ago.  If I end up rewriting it, I'll definitely use `Popup`... it would be a lot easier to work with and I could avoid this issue altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split a single `UserControl` into different places in the logical tree, but you can inject other code into a `Control` and place it around the internal components it defines. This is the model used by `HeaderedContentControl`: two content properties, `Content` and `Header`, which are injected into two different `ContentPresenters` in the control's template. Hence things like `Expander` and `TabItem` with externally defined content in multiple locations around intrinsic parts of the controls. In the case of a `UserControl` you would be placing them in the main XAML instead of a template so the bindings are a little different but the principle is the same.

Define two Dependency properties of type object on your `UserControl` and then bind those into `ContentPresenters` placed in the exact spots where you have "a lot of various nested elements" in your sample. Then when you use the `UserControl` you can just define whatever other elements you want under the `UserControl` element inside like `<MyUserControl.MyContentProperty1>` tags and they'll get placed inside your `UserControl` content.